# Setting background image without zooming in using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to set the background image for an application, however, the image is zoomed in rather then neatly covering the page. How do I get the image to properly fit to the size of the website.

The code looks as follows:

`body {
  background: url(http://www.1zoom.net/big2/155/323865-alexfas01.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-size: cover;`

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> "A keyword that is the inverse of contain. Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container. When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom."

```css
body {
  background: url(http://www.1zoom.net/big2/155/323865-alexfas01.jpg) no-repeat top right;
  background-size: cover;
}
```